# Eclipse Build in Brownser

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, proxy

When I try to run an java web project in eclipse I get the following error message.

While trying to retrieve the URL: `http://{localhost}:8080/{my_project_name}/`
The following error was encountered:

```
Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed
 The system returned: 
              (61) Connection refused          
 The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again. 
Your cache administrator is webmaster.
Generated Mon, 03 Mar 2014 09:01:31 GMT by {Proxy address} (Lusca/LUSCA_HEAD-r14809).
```

I can access the page using the url in firefox without any problems. 
Also the proxy settings are setup in `preferences->network section`.

Please any help is really appriciated.

Comment: have u configured tomcat in eclipse ?? Check for the server settings or restart your server and try again.

Comment: Yes I did I have configured tomcat in eclipse and also tried restarting it couple of times. Did not work.